# Do you need to correlate factor residuals of factors that are measured at the same time point

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, growth-model, misspecification

I am running a second-order (multiple indicator) latent growth curve.
The model has three latent factors (excluding the growth intercept and slope factors) that each have 4-5 indicators. Two of them are time-varying covariates.

My question is, "Do I need to add covariances among the residual variances of the
factors measured at the same time point?"

My sample is children from three different schools and I am assuming that some
time-specific variances may be present. Also, I am guessing this (covarying
factor residuals) needs to be done when running a multivariate growth curve, too.
(two or more trajectories traveling together)

Thank you so much in advance everyone.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer without seeing the exact structure of your model. In the second-order growth part of the model, the first order latent residual variables already account for time-specific variance that is shared among the indicators of the growth process so there would be no need to also allow correlated errors at the same time point for these indicators.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Dr. Geiser! I read through some textbooks and indeed they said so too. Thanks again (and apologies for the late response)